# CSS to change the default look of Bootstrap 4 Nav-tabs

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, tabs

I have created Bootstrap 4 Nav-tabs as below :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home"
      aria-selected="true">SavedAssets</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#submitted" role="tab" aria-controls="profile"
      aria-selected="false">SubmittedAssets</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to change the default look of nav-tabs to be like the below image :
[Tabs image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l1FS.png)

By default, the first tab should be highlighted with a blue line and after clicking on the second tab, the blue line will be moved from the first tab to the second.

Could you please help on writing css for this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add like that, you can got exact result you want and with less use of `!important`

Snippet `CSS` and below `CSS` doing same thing but below `CSS` is the simple and less code

```
.nav-tabs .nav-link, .nav-tabs .nav-link.active, .nav-tabs .nav-link:hover {
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    color: gray;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
    color: #000000;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
.nav-tabs .nav-link {
    color: gray;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link:hover {
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
    color: #000000;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
</style>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home"
        aria-selected="true">SavedAssets</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#submitted" role="tab" aria-controls="profile"
        aria-selected="false">SubmittedAssets</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you , how can i provide the space between two nav tabs

Comment: you can easily do with padding or do you wanna break below line ? if you wanna break line add margin into `nav-item`

Answer (score 0):

In your own css file, just override the bootstrap stylings. Example:

```
.nav-link {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey !important;
  border-color: none !important;
}

.nav-link.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue !important;
  color: #000000 !important;
}
```